# Is there a C++ way to get the min/max value of a scalar?

Tags: c++, c++14

Our unit tests test min/max values. If the underlying data type of the tested variable changes, then the tests needs to be updated - if we spot it & remember to to do so.

If we talk only of `unit8_t`, 16, 32, 64, is there any way to say in the unit test "min/max value of the variable" - as long as it is one of those types?

E.g. if `unit8_t height` becomes `unit16_t height`, I don't want to have to update the min/max unit test.

I am happy if I can do that for those simple tests. Anything else is a bonus.

Comment: Sounds like you may find `decltype` useful.

Comment: If you're only talking about unsigned scalars, you already know the min value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `numeric_limits` to get the the minimum and maximum value for the type:

```cpp
#include <limits>

template<class T>
bool has_min_value(T val) {
    return val == std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest();
}

template<class T>
bool has_max_value(T val) {
    return val == std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8hhGKKfo1)

`lowest()` and `min()` return the same thing for integral types.

For floating-point types, `lowest()` typically returns `-max()` and `min()` returns:

- The minimum finite value.
- For types with subnormal numbers, returns the minimum positive normalized value.

Comment: If I have declared `unsigned short X`, how do I get the min/max values of X? I want to assign them, as well as query them. And, I want the code to still work if I change the declaration of X to `signed` or `long`.  Would `std::numeric_limits<decltype(X)?::min()` work?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica Yes that'll work (assuming `?` was supposed to be `>`), but pay attention to what `min()` returns if you decide to make `X` a floating point in the future. You may want to use `lowest()` (even for integral types).